# vb.net bound controls with web service

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, wcf

Here is the scenario.  Two networks need to talk to eachother.  I have an app that has a local database in our environment that the app talks too. It is using bound controls on a datagrid using vb.net.  Now we want to move the database to the other network and the only way we can have access is this network is using web services.  I have a datagrid that is bound to a database and employee table.  The vb.net code using the fill function and dataset embedded sql to display.  The save function has code such as me.validate() and .endedit() and then uses the update method to update the database from the grid.  I need to strip this out and put it in web methods.  What is the easiest way to do this.  I know the fill is basically a select statement i can retrieve and return a datatable from the web service, but what would be the easiest way to save from the web method. any ideas would be appreciated.  unfortunately this is the way it has to be from the network standpoint.

Comment: See if [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helps.

Comment: fyi its a vb.net desktop app. and the database connection is not on the same network